# what is the structure of $F^{\times}/(F^{\times})^2$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a local field and $F^{\times}$ contains all units. Then what is the structure of $F^{\times}/(F^{\times})^2$ ?

For example if $F=\mathbb{Q}_p$, the p-adic field , then what does $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times})^2$ means and what is its structure ? How does it help us?

Comment: For an abelian group $G$, by $G^2$ you mean the subgroup $\{g^2:g\in G\}$. Right?

Comment: @ajotatxe, so  $F^{\times}/(F^{\times})^2$  is the quotient group of $F^{\times}$ by the subgroup $(F^{\times})^2$. Is it ?

Comment: I may write an answer later. But $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times})^2$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$ if $p \neq 2$ and to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ if $p=2$. This tells you the number of quadratic extensions $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has. Google it, I am sure you'll find a ton of explanations.

Comment: @ParthivBasu, how this tell us the number of quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Kummer theory.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Sorry I am not going to write a complete answer. But in characteristic $\neq 2$, the quadratic extension of any field $F$ is given by $F(\sqrt n)$ where $n \in F$ is not a square. So to count the number quadratic extensions of $F$, you have to count the number of non-trivial cosets in $F^{\times}/(F^{\times})^2$. You need Kummer theory or in general local class field theory if you want to figure out abelian extensions of higher degree. Now to figure out $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times})^2$, you use Hensel's lemma.